# Using correlated mysql subquery, fetch records from same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

Using correlated subquery, i have to find which country on each populated continent has the largest population.
I got the answer but did not understand how it worked for me

```
select Continent, Name, Population 
From Country c
WHERE Population = (
  SELECT MAX(Population) 
  From Country c2
  WHERE c.Continent = c2.Continent
  AND Population > 0
);
```

All records are in same table. Please help me to understand how this query executes and gets the correct results, also please explain me how the aliases c and c2 are working in this query.

Comment: ` WHERE c.Continent = c2` I don't understand this line - and frankly I don't believe it

Comment: I am also confused with the use of aliases here.

Comment: But this query works in real

Comment: Well, you just edited the query

Comment: it has been formatted by someone. former i have uploaded correct query. now would you please assist me regarding the same.